# Add Silence to multiple tracks in Audacity

Tags: audacity

I have hundreds of audio tracks and

> I want to add Silence before all tracks.

I know it can be done through `Chain`, but I do not know how exactly it can be done.

PS: The following I have tried:

`File> Edit Chains` then `File> Apply Chain> Apply to Files`> *selected required files*, the output files are all silenced. I do not know coding, this is the first time I am using Audacity.

I am attaching the **Edit Chains** window.

[image]

Comment: sorry but I do not know Audacity coding, I have modified the question. Kindly have a look.

Comment: Audacity is GUI. If you want to edit hundret of files, you should use a scripting language. AFAIK you can edit audio files with for example Python.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, Audacity provides more easy way to add silence for each of your files.

First import all the tracks and select all. Then follow **Transport > Cursor to > Section Start**

*This path will put your cursor at the beginning (0th mili-second)*

Then **Generate > Silence** path will ask for the duration. (My favorite is hh:mm:ss + miliseconds)

[Sample screen for entering duration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSiz2.png)

After confirmation all of your sounds will be prepared [like here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ0bE.png)

Audacity's chain logic doesn't allow to set duration for silence command, it takes the length of longest track and produce all-silence sounds. This task will be more easy rather than applying chain.

Comment: The next step would be to use the File > Export > Export Multiple... command to export all the updated tracks as separate files.